# Flask URL Parameter is being resolved to different value in the view function

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to render an html table with Flask and Jinja2 where one cell in each row contains a button to download, upload, or edit a particular file in S3. Each time the user uploads a new file in this particular table cell, some backend calculations are executed and then displayed in an adjacent cell. The download/upload buttons should be tied to the key which is in the first cell of that row so that I can validate when a user uploads a file, their filename contains the key for the row they clicked on. My problem is that all buttons in the table are bound to the first key's name instead of the key for the row the button is on. I have inspected these buttons in the browser to make sure the file upload form's action routes to the correct key, and it does, but when I actually upload a file, the key variable in the flask view resolves to the first key for every button in that column.

Jinja2 Template:
Iterates through row of small SQL table that holds application state. Each row is a dict.

```
{% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>row.get('key')</td> <! -- The first cell in every row is the key e.g. (key1, key2, key3...) >
        <td>Extra Info ...</td>
        <td>Extra Info ...</td>
        {% if row.get('data_ready') and row.get('file_exists') %}
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url_for('download_data', key_name=row.get('key'), month=g.month, year=g.year, tag='completed.xlsx') }}">Download Completed File</a>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('upload_data', key_name=row.get('key'), month=g.month, year=g.year, tag='completed.xlsx')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="upload-revision" class="download-upload-button">Upload Revision</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="upload-revision" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            </form>
            <a class="download-upload-button warning" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the completed file?')" 
               href="{{ url_for('delete_file', project_name=row.get('key'), month=g.month, year=g.year, tag='completed.xlsx')}}">Delete Current File</a>
                                    
        </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% if row.get('data_ready') and not row.get('file_exists') %}
            <td class="cell">
                  <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('upload_data', key_name=row.get('key'), month=g.month, year=g.year, tag='completed.xlsx') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <label for="upload-completed-file" class="download-upload-button">Upload Completed File</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="upload-completed-file" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
                  </form>
             </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% if not row.get('data_ready') and not row.get('file_exists') %}
            <td></td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Flask View:

```
@app.route('/upload-data/<key_name>/<month>/<year>/<tag>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_data(key_name, month, year, tag):
    print(key)  # The key at this point is always the first key rendered in the table IF the 
                # row.get('data_ready') and row.get('file_exists') were True. 
                # If only row.get('data_ready') was True, then the only the upload form renders and  
                # the key is correct at this point. 

    # DO THE BUSINESS LOGIC HERE and UPDATE DB
    return redirect(url_for('display_the_main_table'))
```

All other download links/buttons/forms have the correct key when routing to their view function. It's only the 'Upload Revision' form that always uses key1 for the key variable no matter which row is actually clicked. I have tried submitting the key variable to the view function using a hidden  tag with a value="{{ row.get('key') }}" inside of the Upload Revision form tags, but I still only get key1 each time when checking request.form['key'] in the view function. Again, inspecting the elements in the browser shows each form's action mapping to the correct key.

Any ideas on what is happening here and how to fix it?